# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined with pycharm

Tags: django, pycharm

I have the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE problem. I am using Pycharm and under Project Settings -> Django Support everything is set and enabled. Nevertheless I get following error while trying do an import in models.py:

```
from django.db import models

C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Grimbo/PycharmProjects/Muspy/poll/models.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Grimbo/PycharmProjects/Mus/poll/models.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db import models
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    if DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS not in settings.DATABASES:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

print(sys.path):

```
['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2.6.3\\helpers\\pydev', 'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Grimbo\\PycharmProjects\\Mus']
```

Does someone has an idea what's wrong?

Comment: You might have some luck setting an environment variable as mentioned here http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/#RunAndDebug. It would have to point to your project's settings.py

Comment: If that doesn't work google for "setting environment variable windows".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Check out this link](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-django-server.html). Specifically, you want to set the `Environmental Variable` in the configuration. By default, you will see `PYTHONBUFFERED = 1`, and you will want to add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = project.settings` - obviously replacing `project` with the actual name of your project.

Another good thing to do is to go to `File-> Settings -> Django Support ->` and be sure that your Django Root, Settings.py, and Manage.py fields are correct.

Comment: I think you meant `PYTHONUNBUFFERED`.

Answer (score 4):

Following Dan Hoerst's answer worked for me, but it wasn't clear where to set the environment variable. You can find the setting under the menu option:

`Run -> Edit Configurations...`

Expand the `Django Server` option on the left hand side and then select your project. There you will find the `Environment Variables:` setting. Remember to use the dotted path like `Muspy.settings` and not the file path.

Dan, I'd reply to your answer, but don't have the rep.